# PDO returns wrong value

Tags: php, pdo

I'm totally new to PDO so I apologize if I made a simple mistake here. Also if this has been answered before. I searched but couldn't find. My problem is that when I print the sessions it prints out 'Array ( [user_id] => 1 )' but the username and password I entered is for user_id 2. I have tried this with a differant username and password and it still gives an id value of 1. So I echoed out $user_id before the session is created and it is 1. But I can't figure out where it is getting this 1 from? Because there is no id of 1 in the database. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here is the code from my login file:

```
<?php
require 'core.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);

    $hash = $stmt->execute();
    $password_verified = password_verify($password, $hash);

    if ($password_verified = true) {
        $stmt_id = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt_id->bindParam(1, $username);

        $user_id = $stmt_id->execute();
        echo $user_id;

        $id_num_rows = $stmt_id->rowCount();
        if ($id_num_rows == 0) {
            echo 'You have entered a wrong password';
        }else if($id_num_rows == 1){

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            print_r($_SESSION);
        }
    } else {
        echo("Please enter a username and password.");
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>

</header>
<body>
<form action ="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="post">
<div class='field'>
    <label for="username">Username: </label><input type='text'   
                                             name='username'/><br>
</div>

<div class='field'>
    <label for ="password">Password: </label><input type='password' 
                                              name='password'/>
</div>

<div class='field'>
    <label for='remember'>
        <input type='checkbox' name="remember" id="remember"/> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
<input type='submit' value='Log in'/>

</form>
</body>
</html>

<And here is the code from core.inc.php

<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.inc.php';

ob_start();
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
@$http_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

?>

<Core.inc.php uses connect.inc.php which is added below:
<?php
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=goal;charset=utf8','root','');
var_dump($db);
echo 'connected';
}
catch(Exception $e){
echo 'Error 1 has occured';
}
?>
```

Comment: I am not getting you are accepting password but not using that for varification

Comment: You're not fetching the PDO result set (`execute()` doesn't do that). Once you fix that (see dupe) your code should run

Comment: @Machavity thanks alot. Really helped alot.

Comment: In addition to the solution(s) to your immediate problem: Why are you querying the user record twice? And why are you testing rowCount() for the second query, but not for the first query? Better request the id together with the password (hash), test whether _that_ query returns a record. And if it does and the hash matches just assign the id - wihtout a second query.

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
if ($password_verified = true) {
```

is very incorrect because you're basically just assigning `true` to `$password_verified`. You should just be doing a `if($password_verified)` though, I am not sure if it will solve your problem.

You are also not parsing the results as you should be using `fetchAll()` and then going through the results to see if the user exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt_id->execute();
```

Returns true on succes, or false on failure, you need to use the result of the query (and not the status of the execution):

```
 $stmt_id->fetchAll()
```

Also you have an error here, you need to use comparison and not assignment:

```
if ($password_verified = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt_id->execute()` will return `bool`, in your case it's `true` and later converted to `int`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

You need to `fetch` the data in order to retrieve the `user_id`.